# extracting and plotting atomic coordinates from pdb file python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to extract just the alpha carbon coordinates and plot them in a 3D representation. The top half of the following code works fine, but I can't seem to plot my results.

```
import re
import glob
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


coord = []
pattern = re.compile('ATOM\s{5,}\d+\s{2}CA\s{2,}\w{3}\s\w\s{2,}\d+\s{6}\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s{2}\d+\.\d+', flags=re.S)
for file in glob.glob('file_rank_1.pdb'):
with open(file) as fp:
    for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
        output = result[-22:]
        coord = " ".join(output.split())
        coord = coord.replace(" ",",")
        c = coord.split(',')
        print(c)
X,Y,Z = (c)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
plt.show()
```

My results from running the above looks like...

```
['72.438', '109.283', '43.980']
['75.664', '110.907', '45.079']
['74.354', '111.094', '48.594']
['73.380', '107.449', '48.722']
['76.614', '106.603', '46.958']
['79.740', '105.625', '48.895']
['82.425', '107.703', '47.318']
['80.088', '110.405', '46.265']
['78.710', '110.389', '49.818']
['82.235', '110.471', '51.200']
['82.841', '113.550', '49.133']
['79.233', '114.754', '49.675']
['78.633', '113.745', '53.295']
['77.041', '117.182', '53.503']
['73.963', '116.530', '51.505']
['73.696', '113.058', '52.933']
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

The above code opens the graph interface, but it remains blank. There is also a full screen of red file messages from the interactive shell that I left off to try to save space in this question.
How can I plot the numbers found in c? Thanks

Comment: You don't have any numbers in `c`. They are strings.

Comment: I tried turning them to floats, but must have misused the command, as when I did it caused more problems than solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to point out:

1) In the following block, `c` is a list of strings not floats.

```
with open(file) as fp:
    for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
        output = result[-22:]
        coord = " ".join(output.split())
        coord = coord.replace(" ",",")
        c = coord.split(',')
        print(c)
```

You can change them using:

```
[float(i) for i in c]
```

2) When you set `X,Y,Z = (c)`, that `c` is only the last item in the loop. So you should `append` each `c` within the loop to collect all coordinates.

3) You might want to use `numpy` for array manipulations.

So hopefully the following will work:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import glob
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


points = []
pattern = re.compile('ATOM\s{5,}\d+\s{2}CA\s{2,}\w{3}\s\w\s{2,}\d+\s{6}\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s{2}\d+\.\d+', flags=re.S)
for file in glob.glob('file_rank_1.pdb'):
with open(file) as fp:
    for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
        output = result[-22:]
        coord = " ".join(output.split())
        coord = coord.replace(" ",",")
        c = coord.split(',')
        c = [float(i) for i in c] # change them to float
        points.append(c)
        print(c)

X,Y,Z=np.array(points).T
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
plt.show()
```